# D3 access html attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the following code to loop through all rect nodes:

```
d3.selectAll("svg g rect")
    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
        console.log(this);
});
```

Console.log prints:

```
<rect class="cls" name="UK" style="fill: #fdb462;" transform="translate(52 50)" x="805.625" y="0" width="13.75" height="229.018" >...</rect>
```

How can I access name attribute (having value `"UK"`) of rect tag? I tried `this.name` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic D3 way to get the value of `name` is using `selection.attr()` as a **getter**:

```
d3.select(this).attr("name")
```

Here is the demo:

```js
d3.select("rect")
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    console.log(d3.select(this).attr("name"));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect class="cls" name="UK" style="fill: #fdb462;" transform="translate(52 50)" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100"></rect>
</svg>
```

Internally, `selection.attr()` uses [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) (or `getAttributeNS`). Therefore, it's equivalent to:

```
this.getAttribute("name")
```

And here is the demo:

```js
d3.select("rect")
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    console.log(this.getAttribute("name"));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect class="cls" name="UK" style="fill: #fdb462;" transform="translate(52 50)" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100"></rect>
</svg>
```